# Can't Connect to a Database on IPOWER hosting - PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

Please help me connect to a DB - I need to get this to work:

```
<?php
require_once 'general.php';

try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=account.ipowermysql.com;dbname=zipcodes', 'user', 'password');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print 'Oh SNAP ... Error!: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br/>';
    die();
}
```

If i run it as is, i get a 500 error page.

If I add ***?>*** at the end, I get a blank page.

If I run "DB-connect" code generated by  IPOWER it works.

IPOWER generated code:

```
 <?php 
$link = mysql_connect('account.ipowermysql.com', 'user', 'password'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connected successfully'; 
mysql_select_db(zipcodes); 
?>
```

I guess the server is configured not to show PHP errors, but a 500 error page instead...

PS - here is general.php code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
@ob_start();
session_start();

function echo_session($arg) {
    if(isset($_SESSION[$arg])) {
        return $_SESSION[$arg];
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

PS2 - original code (at the top) works on GoDaddy and MediaTemple ... it's something with IPOWER ...

I'm a noob and I need this to work, but don't know how to.

Please help

Comment: add echo "works"; before } catch (PDOException $e) and test

Comment: @LuckyChingi do I need to include general.php?

Comment: @LuckyChingi - yea, it prints "works" ... I must be missing something ... let me doublecheck

Comment: Your code works fine then :)

Comment: if you add ?> at the end of the file and get a blank page, it means that the connection has successfully created. so the question is that why do you think there is a problem or you're missing something? do you get any errors afterwards?

Comment: @EhsanT the problem with IPOWER is that instead of showing PHP error message they show generig 500 error page...  so I could not troublshoot. Original code har ?> and was working fine on GoDaddy ... but not on IPOWER ... Turns out there was a problem with DB - table was named differently ... now all is working  - thank you all. PS - how do I close this question?

Comment: OK, if you have access to `php.ini` of your host you can change it accordingly to show the error messages. if not, you may manually add settings in your code to show the errors by adding these two lines: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`. if none of these work, you still have a way of troubleshooting but that's a little slow, but it works. you have to trace your code and add something like `die('error');` before and after the lines which you think are generating the error and check if you see these text. if so, continues on, if not, that's where the error occurs.